# Java weak reference is not freed after System.gc()

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection, system, weak

I've got a simple snippet:

```
Integer integer = 2;
WeakReference<Integer> wi = new WeakReference<>(integer);
WeakReference<Integer> sr = new WeakReference<>(new Integer(3));
System.out.println(wi.get());
System.out.println(sr.get());
System.gc();
System.out.println("step 1 wi = " + wi.get());
System.out.println("step 1 sr =: " + sr.get());
integer = null;
System.gc();
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
System.out.println("step 1 wi = " + wi.get());
System.out.println("step 1 sr =: " + sr.get());
```

The "System.gc()" call should force all weak reference to be recycled, right, and I even waited 1 second to make sure gc() happens.
But even when "integer = null" is set, "wi" refuse to be null. While sr is null right after "System.gc()". It prints:

```
2
3
step 1 wi = 2
step 1 sr =: null
step 1 wi = 2
step 1 sr =: null
```

My questions:
(1) What is the core difference between wi and sr?
(2 )how to make jvm recycle wi?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You should hook up to the gc notification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html in order to be sure that the GC was really performed at the time you check these values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing whatsoever to do with either the fact that `System.gc()` makes no guarantees (it doesn't, but that's not why you're seeing what you're seeing), or how weak references interact with gc.

The j.l.Integer class holds a 'cache' of instances for `Integer`, for all byte values, so, from -128 to +127. You can watch this in action:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(127) == Integer.valueOf(127));
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(128) == Integer.valueOf(128));
```

The above prints `true false`.

This code:

```
Integer x = 2;
```

is syntax sugar. What the compiler actually ends up compiling, because 'autoboxing' is a figment of javac's imagination (the JVM knows nothing about it, it's entirely javac doing that for you), is this code:

```
Integer x = Integer.valueOf(2);
```

whereas, of course, if you call `new Integer`, you ALWAYS get a new object, because, well, that's what the spec says. You can test this too:

```
System.out.println(new Integer(5) == new Integer(5));
```

the above prints `false`.

Effectively, the `java.lang.Integer` class itself holds a reference to the thing your `wi` reference points to, hence, it never gets collected.

Retry the exact same code, but this time, instead of ' = 2', try ' = 128', and this time it'll collect same as sr will.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki Please explain _could change anytime_. All of the behavior explained in this answer is well documented in the Javadoc and Java language specification.

Comment: @KrzysztofCichocki You're wrong. While I agree that relying on the Integer cache feels strange, this answer is exact. Concerning the WeakReference, it won't get cleared as long the referenced object is strongly reachable from the Integer cache.

Comment: Relying on internal cache is not good, this is just implemenation detail and could be changed anytmie.

Comment: System.gc() is not guaranteed to really run the gc, it just kindly asks the jvm to do so. Again this is just an implementation detail that you can't rely on so precisely, same as JComponent.repaint() and Thread.yeld(), although these calls typically have some effect, you can't be really guaranteed that they will really run the underlying task in some specifc timing.

Comment: You should hook up to the gc notification: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/GarbageCollectionNotificationInfo.html in order to be sure that the GC was really performed at the time you check these values